# If $a_n=1+n+n^2$ how do you compute the $gcd(a_n+1,a_{n+s})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Question: If $n$ is a positive number I write $a(n) =1+n+n^2$. Let $s$
>   be a fixed positive number. Is it true the $\gcd(a_n+1, a_{n+s})$ will be a
>   divisor of $1+5s^2+s^4$?

For example if $n=1$ and $s=3$ then $\gcd(4,21)=1$ which is a divisor of $1+5*3^2+3^4=127$, since $1 |127$. On the other hand if $n=106$ then $\gcd(10922,11557)=127$ and $127 |127$.

Comment: Just computing stuff. Not sure where to start. I know that $a(n+s)=1+n+s+n^2+2ns+s^2$.

Comment: I would try to find a recurrence there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g = \gcd(a_n + 1, a_{n+s}) \\= \gcd(n^2 + n + 2, (n+s)^2 + (n+s) + 1) \\= \gcd(n^2 + n + 2, s^2 + 2ns + s - 1)$

So if we have $u \cdot (n^2 + n + 2) + v \cdot (s^2 + 2ns + s - 1) = g$, we can apply the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm) for polynomials to get:

$(\frac{4s^2}{s^4+5s^2+1}) \cdot (n^2 + n + 2) + (\frac{s^2-2ns-s-1}{s^4+5s^2+1}) \cdot (s^2 + 2ns + s - 1) = 1$

Multiply to flatten the expression:

$(4s^2) \cdot (n^2 + n + 2) + (s^2-2ns-s-1) \cdot (s^2 + 2ns + s - 1) = s^4+5s^2+1$

This means $\gcd(a_n + 1, a_{n+s})$ must divide $s^4+5s^2+1$, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Actually you might have glossed over way to much for me to follow this answer directly.

Comment: The main steps I glossed over are contained in the Wikipedia link, which explains how to find $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Actually I am stuck here: $\gcd(n^2+n+2,(n+s)^2+(n+s)+1)=gcd(n^2+n+2,s^2+2ns+s-1)$. I am not sure how you eliminated terms?

Comment: $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a-b, b) = \gcd(a, b-a)$. In this case I subtracted the left side from the right.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for !